# How does authlogic save the session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, authlogic

I use the plugin authlogic for my rails application (rails 2). 
How the data will be saved in the session via authlogic? It is safe enough?

For example, if I save `session[:group_id] = 1` in it, it will be saved on the client PC in a cookie? If yes, how I can change the session-settings, so that It will be saved on the server side and not on client side ?

Do you have any hints, how I can save data in a safe modus, that survives several requests without using a cookie ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose where to store the session in your application:

- CookieStore - Stores everything on the client.
- DRBStore - Stores the data on a DRb client.
- MemCacheStore - Stores the data in MemCache.
- ActiveRecordStore - Stores the data in a database using ActiveRecord.

In the `config/environment.rb` file:

```
# Set to one of [:active_record_store, :drb_store, :mem_cache_store, :cookie_store]
config.action_controller.session_store = :active_record_store
```

There is also an oficial guide on security when using sessions http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did it some months ago, and it does not worked somehow. But now I cleared the cache and the cookies, and now it works. Thx.

Comment: As far as I can see https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/session.rb , it uses `controller.session` which is handled by Rails. I doubt they would reinvent the whole session storage mechanism.

Comment: Authlogic does not affect the rails session. If you're using authlogic and storing stuff on the session, it's still going to use whatever session store rails is configured to use.

Authlogic does store it's own cookie (user_credentials by default) which is for authlogic's internal use, but that's separate from the rails session.